# Call to external DLL from C# with integer pointer

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop

I'm trying to call an external .dll function from c#.  The doc for the dll defines the function:

```
int funcName(int *retVal)
```

I've tried various configurations and always the unbalanced stack error from p/invoke; My c# code currently looks like this:

```
[DLLImport("dllName");
unsafe static extern int funcName(ref IntPtr retVal);
unsafe IntPtr retNum;
int status = funcName(ref retNum);
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: It is more like C than C++...

Comment: What is the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) for the external DLL?

Comment: It is a C library; sorry for the mistaken tag.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: There's nothing here that is more of C or more of C++.  `int (int*)` is a perfectly reasonable function type in C++.  And even if the signature is C-compatible, as is common for DLL exports, the compiler mode is important.  C code fed to a C++ compiler does not act like C.  For example, it gets name-mangled by default.

Comment: @BenVoigt: except that, in C++, you would use reference. Pointer output argument _really_ is C coding, and well ... better suited for that tag, respectively.

Comment: Also, `[DLLImport("dllName");` is wrong. It seems `;` should be replaced with `]`. It is only probably a posting issue though. Also, please always paste the exact error message, too.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Not on a DLL boundary, you wouldn't use a reference type.  And pointer arguments are fine in C++.  And code written in C style and compiled with a C++ compiler requires the `c++` tag, not the `c` tag.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I am honestly lost. What are you talking about? You would not use reference in a C++ interface, but pointer? Seriously?!

Comment: @HankBrandenburg: Is your DLL function in a `.c` or `.cpp` file?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Seriously, I don't use C++ references in a cross-language interface.  The implementation language should not infect the interface.  Also, yes I would use a pointer for an output argument in C++.  Explicit aliasing beats hidden aliasing any day.

Comment: @BenVoigt: ah, you are one of those "C alike C++ programmers" rather than using either of those languages cleanly...

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Oh baloney.  I am one of the C++ programmers who understands the language well enough to know that references are not magic pixie dust that fixes problems of pointers.  I know my tools and I use them intelligently.  Quite apart from that, DLL export functions should only use C compatible signatures.  Ever.  Because C++-specific signatures aren't handled consistently by different compilers.

Comment: I already wrote C interface is a C question. Why would you pretend it is a C++ interface; it simply is _not_. I am not sure what you are trying to debate about it, or even why.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: If you don't know that your "C interface" will get name mangled by a C++ compiler, you should stay far away from this question and others like it.  The compiler determines the language rules in effect, and therefore the tag.  DLLs use "C interfaces", yes.  And **how to get a "C interface" from a C++ compiler is a C++ question, and gets the `c++` tag.**

Comment: The OP has never mentioned that it is C++ interface, nor does it look like one, nor is the the OP having extern "C", etc. You can argue this to death, but it looks like as simply wrong tagging from the OP based on the content.

Comment: @HankBrandenburg: is it a C or C++ dll?

Comment: Adam NAthan's book is the bible for pinvoke. https://www.amazon.com/NET-COM-Complete-Interoperability-Guide/dp/067232170X

Answer (score 7):

Your p/invoke declaration has the wrong parameter type.

- `ref Int32` is the correct match for `int*`.
- `IntPtr` can also work.
- `ref IntPtr` would be `int**`.  Definitely not what you want.

Use

```
[DLLImport("dllName")]
static extern int funcName(ref Int32 retVal);
```

Also make sure that the calling convention matches.  You should never use a dllexport in C or C++ without also using an explicit calling convention, and then the C# DllImport needs to have the matching convention.

Generally the prototype in C++ should be

```
extern "C" int __stdcall funcName(int* arg);
```

Is there a header file provided for C and C++ clients that you could check to verify the signature?

Comment: Thanks Ben - this worked perfectly after I specified the Cdecl convention and used ref Int32. MANY THANKS for your help!