# Crash when calling c++ dll function from c#

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to call the following function from c#.
I tried a few approached but it always crashes when i call it

This is the export from the .H File

```
LPCTSTR  _EXPORT_ GetString(LPCTSTR Name,int far *errCode);
```

This is my (not working) code at the moment:

```
[DllImport("External.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern string GetString(string VarName, out int ErrorCode);

public string GetStringW(string VarName, out int ErrorCode)
{
   return GetString(VarName, out ErrorCode);
}
```

Comment: An `LPCTSTR` is not a C# string.

Comment: a * in c++ means pointer.  have a look here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325668/call-to-external-dll-from-c-sharp-with-integer-pointer

Comment: I tried it with ref Int32 ErrorCode but it still crashes

Comment: LPCTSTR is not Unicode if the DLL is compiled with MBCS character set as the setting.  Second, what is `far`?

Comment: There are two issues with your code.  1) your code doesn't return a value a LPCTSTR it is returning string.   2) ErrorCode must be defined before GetString() is called.

Comment: Thank you it is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the return parameter, changed it to intptr, that solved the issue