# C# PInvoke pass reference to int[]

Tags: c#, winapi, visual-c++, pinvoke

I'm trying to pass an int[8] reference to a C++ DLL, but a `System.ExecutionEngineException` is thrown in C# when it returns. Here is the C++ code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall ReadFlashCfg(int* flData);
int __stdcall ReadFlashCfg(int* flData)
{
    return mctl.ReadFlashCfg(flData);
}// breakpoint here shows flData is correct
```

And the C# DLL wrapper code:

```
[DllImport(MyDllPath)]
private static extern int ReadFlashCfg(ref int[] fData);

public static int[] ReadFlashCfgNoRc()
{
   var flData = new int[8];
   var rc = ReadFlashCfg(ref flData); //Exception happens here
   if (rc != 0) throw new Exception(rc.ToString());
   return flData;
}
```

And the C# calling code:

```
var fd = ReadFlashCfgNoRc();
```

A breakpoint on the very last line of the C++ code shows the array populated with correct data.

The exception happens upon returning from `ReadFlashCfg(ref flData)` in the DLL wrapper.

I think I need to let the C++ know the size of the array (it's always 8) so that it can manage the stack correctly.

I know I can pass eight individual int*, but there has to be simpler way - is there?

Comment: What is the `ReturnCode`? Why do you return this type instead of `int` in C++ dll?

Comment: ReturnCode is an int. That was a typo in the question and now corrected.

Comment: Remove the `ref`

Comment: Agree with @DavidHeffernan, `Int[]` type should be passed directly here.(Quickly tested and works fine for me) For "*I need to let the C++ know the size of the array*", The common method is to pass size as a parameter.

Comment: @DavidHeffman - That fixes it, but I do not understand why that works. The C++ parameter is `int*`, which I thought requires a `ref`' on the P/Invoke side so that the modified parameter is returned to the .NET. Submit as the answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 0):

[Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) pass an argument by reference.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23325773/10611792) says:

- `ref Int32` is the correct match for `int*`.
- `Int[]`(@DavidHeffman pointed out) and `IntPtr` can also work. (use `Marshal::AllocHGlobal(8*sizeof(Int32))`to Assign `IntPtr` size, `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(IntPtr)` to release)
- `ref Int[]` would be `int**`, and the size of `Int[]` will be incorrectly converted to 1.

For "*I need to let the C++ know the size of the array*", The common method is to pass size as a parameter.